# 4 Dimensional Meshgrid - matlab

Tags: matlab, grid

I want to create a 4 dimensional meshgrid. 
I know I need to use the ngrid function. However, the output of meshgrid and ngrid is not exactly the same unless one permutes dimensions.

To illustrate, a three dimensional meshgrid seems to be equivalent to a three dimensional ngrid if the following permutations are done:

```
[X_ndgrid,Y_ndgrid,Z_ndgrid] = ndgrid(1:3,4:6,7:9)
X_meshgrid = permute(X_ndgrid,[2,1,3]);
Y_meshgrid = permute(Y_ndgrid,[2,1,3]);
Z_meshgrid = permute(Z_ndgrid,[2,1,3]);
sum(sum(sum(X == X_meshgrid))) == 27
sum(sum(sum(Y == Y_meshgrid))) == 27
sum(sum(sum(Z == Z_meshgrid))) == 27
```

I was wondering what are the right permutations for a 4-D meshgrid.

```
[X_ndgrid,Y_ndgrid,Z_ndgrid, K_ndgrid] = ndgrid(1:3,4:6,7:9,10:12 )
```

Edit: EBH, thanks for your answer below. Just one more quick question. If the endgoal is to create a grid in order to use interpn, what would be the difference between creating a grid with meshgrid or with ndgrid (assuming a 3 dimensional problem?)

Comment: small tips: instead of `sum(sum(sum(X == X_mesh)))` you can write `sum(X(:) == X_mesh(:))`

Comment: Thanks. That was just a cross-check - didn't spend much time thinking about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `meshgrid` and `ndgrid` is that `meshgrid` order the first input vector by the columns, and the second by the rows, so:

```
>> [X,Y] = meshgrid(1:3,4:6)
X =
     1     2     3
     1     2     3
     1     2     3
Y =
     4     4     4
     5     5     5
     6     6     6
```

while `ndgrid` order them the other way arround, like:

```
>> [X,Y] = ndgrid(1:3,4:6)
X =
     1     1     1
     2     2     2
     3     3     3
Y =
     4     5     6
     4     5     6
     4     5     6
```

After the first 2 dimensions, there is no difference between them, so using `permute` only on the first 2 dimensions should be enough. So for 4 dimensions you just write:

```
[X_ndgrid,Y_ndgrid,Z_ndgrid,K_ndgrid] = ndgrid(1:3,4:6,7:9,10:12);
[X_meshgrid,Y_meshgrid,Z_meshgrid] = meshgrid(1:3,4:6,7:9);
X_meshgrid_p = permute(X_meshgrid,[2,1,3]);
Y_meshgrid_p = permute(Y_meshgrid,[2,1,3]);
all(X_ndgrid(1:27).' == X_meshgrid_p(:)) % the transpose is only relevant for this comparison, not for the result.
all(Y_ndgrid(1:27).' == Y_meshgrid_p(:)) % the transpose is only relevant for this comparison, not for the result.
all(Z_ndgrid(1:27).' == Z_meshgrid(:)) % the transpose is only relevant for this comparison, not for the result.
```

and it will return:

```
ans =
     1
ans =
     1
ans =
     1
```

If you want to use it as an input for `interpn`, [you should use the `ndgrid` format](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interpn.html?searchHighlight=interpn#inputarg_X1X2Xn).

Comment: Does this also work with the 4D? If you compare the x,y,z of the 4D with the x,y,z of the meshgrid, do they matxh after the permute?

Comment: @ EBH, Could you please write the code for the 4-D case as I asked? Not clear on how to write that.

Comment: @AnderBiguri see my edit, there is no `meshgrid` for 4D, so you can only compare the first 3D.

Comment: That is exactly what I suggested yes. But now permute is not enough it seems, its also transpose? How about if you do 5D?

Comment: @EBH, exactly. My question what would a 4 dimensional meshgrid return?

Comment: @volcompt There is no 4 dimensional `meshgrid` function

Comment: @AnderBiguri the permute is enough, I only transpose so I can compare  to `X_meshgrid_p(:)` directly, because `X_ndgrid(1:27)` returns a row vector. everything stay the same for 5D and for any ND.

Comment: you are absolutely rigth

Comment: @EBH, thanks for your answer. I guess it is almost clear now. I have just edit my question with another small point - which might clarify my issue.